# React Native keyboard is dismissed automatically in react-native-tab-view

Tags: react-native

Here is my code

```
<TabView
            keyboardDismissMode='none'
            navigationState={{index, routes}}
            renderTabBar={renderTabBar}
            renderScene={renderScene}
            initialLayout={{width: layout.width}}
            onIndexChange={() => {}}
          />
```

I am using react-native-tab-view with three tabs in my application also I have TextInput inside third tab. I had set autofocus={true} to open the keyboard automatically when third tab is opened. But the issue is when I swipe second tab to third tab the keyboard is closing automatically. I want the keyboard should not close until the user tries to close.

Answer (score 0):

My render scene is

```
const scaneMap = ({route}) => {
        switch (route?.key) {
            case "stepOne":
                return stepOne()
            case "stepTwo":
                return stepTwo()
            case "stepThree":
                return stepThree()
            default:
                return stepOne()
        }
    }
```

Similar to your problem, the keyboard was closing every time I pressed a key on the input. As a solution, I changed the structure as follows and the problem was fixed.
const scaneMap = ({route}) => {
switch (route?.key) {
case "stepOne":
return stepOne()
case "stepTwo":
return stepTwo()
case "stepThree":
return stepThree()
default:
return stepOne()
}
}

Comment: i have tried this but doesn't work

Comment: yeah don't use `SceneMap()`